# Show only today's events in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, firebase, momentjs

I'm trying to print out only events that are scheduled for "today" in an ng-repeat. I've got a section that shows all of the events, which is currently working great. Here is the code for that:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">


          <div ng-repeat="event in events | limitTo:100 | filter:tfilter | orderBy: 'date' | filterPastDates">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>{{event.date | amDateFormat:'MMMM Do'}}</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>{{event.name}}</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Using the filterPastDates filter, the events that have passed are deleted. I used the method below to fix a problem I had where today's events were being deleted:

```
angular.module('zenCityApp')
.filter('filterPastDates', function () {
  return function (events) {
    if (events && events.length) {
      var filtered = [];
      var cutOffDate = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'millisecond');
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var evt = events[i];
        if (cutOffDate.isBefore(evt.date)) {
          filtered.push(evt);
        }
      }
      return filtered;
    } else {
      return events;
    }
  };
});
```

I'm trying to make a section that shows only today's events, but I can't get it working. Here is the html (right now I'm just trying to get it to print out the date):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
        <h2>Today's Events</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
          <div ng-repeat "event in events | orderBy: 'date' | eventDateFilter">
            <h4>{{event.date | amDateFormat:'MMMM Do'}}</h4>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

And here is the filter I am trying to use, based off the one I used above:

```
      angular.module('zenCityApp')
.filter('eventDateFilter', function () {
  return function (events) {
    if (events && events.length) {
      var eventsToday = [];
      var startOfDay = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'millisecond');
      var endOfDay = moment().endOf('day');
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var evt = events[i];
        if (startOfDay <= evt.date <= endOfDay) {
          eventsToday.push(evt);
        }
      }
      return eventsToday;
    }
  };
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In what way is it not working? Did you try putting a breakpoint in your filter and stepping through the code?

Comment: Right off the bat I see that filtered.push(evt); in yours should be eventsToday.push(evt);

Comment: are you sure evt.date can be strictly  equal to cutOffDate ? Shouldn't you bracket it between startOf('day') and endOf('day') instead ?

Comment: @Sycomor thanks that's helping me get closer. Here's what I have now, which is printing out all of my events. I think my logic is just a little off:

Comment: see the updated code above

Comment: What date format do you use? Date object, string or timestamp? I made a fiddle for JS date objects: http://jsfiddle.net/yok7du6x/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't chain inequality checks : `startOfDay <= evt.date <= endOfDay` is not a pertinent boolean check :it is actually valid but is equivalent to `(startOfDay <= evt.date) <= endOfDay` or `(true | false) <= endOfDay` which is, for all intents and purposes, always true.

Just do a double check : `if (startOfDay.isBefore(evt.date) && evt.date.isBefore(endOfDay)) ...` should give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, @Sycomor! Something similar worked before I saw your comment:


        if (startOfDay <= moment(evt.date)) {
          if(moment(evt.date) <= endOfDay) {
              eventsToday.push(evt);
            }
        }
      }
      return eventsToday;